# Fluentd logs not sent to Elasticsearch - pattern not match

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, serilog, fluentd

I can't get log messages to be processed by Fluentd and sent to Elasticsearch. I'm tailing the container of my service, it will pick up the log, but it can't parse it, it always fails with the error **pattern not match**. I understand that something is wrong with my parsing setup, but I can't see what.

The service writes to Stdout with Serilog, using the ElasticsearchJsonFormatter. My understanding is that it will write valid json to the console. This appears to be happening if I view the logs of the running container. When I view the Fluentd logs, it looks as if it has all been escaped.

If I view the logs of the service pod I can see the message, if then view the logs of the fluentd pod I can see the pattern not match error. Both of these are included below.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this for days now.

### Serilog Setup

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .WriteTo.Console(new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter())
                 .MinimumLevel.Information()
                 .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                 .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning);
```

### Fluentd Config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
data:
  fluent.conf: |
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/my-service-*.log
      pos_file /var/log/app.log.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type json
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>
    </source>

    <match **>
      @type elasticsearch
      host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
      port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
      user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
      password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
      index_name fluentd
      type_name fluentd
    </match>
```

### Example log message

This is what I can see if I view the logs for the running container. In my case this is a Kubernetes pod.

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2021-12-29T13:23:28.2692128+00:00",
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "Get Record - User Claim Contracts: {contracts} All Claims: {allclaims}",
    "message": "Get Record - User Claim Contracts: [1, 2, 3, 4] All Claims: \"Application.Claims\"",
    "fields": {
        "contracts": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ],
        "allclaims": "Application.Claims",
        "ddsource": "application",
        "RecordId": null,
        "UserId": null,
        "TransactionId": null,
        "env": "UAT",
    }
}
```

### Fluentd pattern not match

This is what I see when I view the logs for the fluentd container. Again, this is a pod.

```
2021-12-29 13:37:48 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not match: "2021-12-29T13:37:47.852294372Z stdout F {\"@timestamp\":\"2021-12-29T13:37:47.8518242+00:00\",\"level\":\"Information\",\"messageTemplate\":\"Get Record - User Claim Contracts: {contracts} All Claims: {allclaims}\",\"message\":\"Get Record - User Claim Contracts: [1, 2, 3, 4] All Claims: \\\"Application.Claims\\\"\",\"fields\":{\"contracts\":[1,2,3,4],\"allclaims\":\"\",\"ddsource\":\"\",\"RecordId\":null,\"UserId\":null,\"TransactionId\":null,\"env\":\"UAT\",\"\":\"\",\"\":\"\"}}"
```

Comment: Why do you need JSON parsing? The `fluent.conf` in the ConfigMap doesn't contain any intermediate steps before routing to ElasticSearch. You can simply skip the parsing and send them directly using the [none](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/none) parser plugin. BTW, the timestamp format seems like a mismatch in the current configuration.

Comment: That's a good question. Truthfully I'm just getting started and thought it was required. I'll try it out with the none plugin and see how it goes.

Comment: OK, using the none parser plugin does send the log to elastic, but it doesn't format it in anyway. Usually it break all the properties out, but I am just seeing the json as a string. I think I must need the parser for this. Can you also advise what is wrong with the date format? I've had a look at it and I can't see a problem.

Comment: Hey @Jim, do you have a solution yet? I'm running into similar issues...

Answer (score 0):

Your log message is not valid JSON, since it contains a comma in line `"env": "UAT",`. The Fluentd log writes out two more empty fields `"":""` as part of your record.

To parse time fields, you have to tell Fluentd the name of the `time_key`, in your case with `time_key: @timestamp`. You can use `%iso8601` as `time_format`. For details see [the Fluentd documentation on time parameters.](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/parse-section#time-parameters)

Comment: Ah this is my mistake, the actual json is valid, but I removed a couple of bits to make it shorter for Stack Overflow. I will try out the datetime changes you recommend.